# How to get the focused item within a caph list be always in first position?

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

Using Caph 3.1.0, I have a list of n focusable elements within a caph-list.

While scrolling, I would like the focused element to always be at position 1. E.g. the entire list scrolls and not the cursor. This way the user always looks at the same place on the screen while hitting arrow keys.

What I currently have:

```
el1.focused el2 el3 el4 ...
then hit right arrow key
el1 el2.focused el3 el4 ... (the user's eyes have to move to the right to see the focused element)
```

What I would like:

```
el1.focused el2 el3 el4 ...
then hit right arrow key
el2.focused el3 el4 el5 ... (the user's eyes did not have to move, the entire list scrolled)
```

Is this possible with Caph? I could not find anything into the documentation for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replying to myself in case it "helps" someone else:

I wrote to caph@samsung.com and here is their answer:
"The  current version(3.1.x) caph-list does not support auto always focus the most left item. Users can try to use "on-scroll-finish" event to focus the most left item when scroll finishes."

Regards